# shell script gives output in 2 lines I need only 1

Tags: linux, shell, awk, pipe

I have the following commands saved in a *.sh* file

```
prog=$1
ps axf | grep $prog | grep -v grep | awk '{print "kill -9 " $1}'
```

I get the following output when I execute it

```
kill -9 3184
kill -9 20359
```

But I just need the first line of it as that is the only valid pid. How can I remove the 2nd line from the output.

Comment: It's better to use `pkill`. Don't reinvent the wheel!

Comment: what is the o/p of `ps axf | grep $prog | grep -v grep` ?

Comment: `grep` followed by `awk` is an anti-pattern. You should use `awk '!/grep/ { ... }` to process all lines without the string "grep". Pipes and forks are expensive operations.

Comment: Another anti-pattern: kill -9. Any program that isn't killed by one of `-INT`, `-HUP` or `-QUIT` has a bug. You should use one of those three to allow the program being killed to clean up some of the resources it uses (e.g. remove temp files).

Comment: @IporSircer pkill worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with what you want to do:

- You're building a chain of 4 commands for something relatively simple
- You're going to get as a result only the first line of a list of processes containing `$prog` (excluding the `grep $prog` which you filtered out); how can you be sure that's the process you want?

The correct command to use is

```
pkill $prog`
```

as suggested in the comments, which probably will do what you want.

Just for information, and to answer your question, you can pipe an output to `head -n 1` to return only the first line:

```
<list of commands> | head -n 1
```

However, in your case this would add a fifth command to the chain, so I recommend you don't do it this way.